# how to upload multiple text files and save path to MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am looking for a code that how to upload multiple text files to be input in different input fields like

```html
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="file" name="file2">
```

these files should be text files,upload to the specified directory and save this path to MySQL database later get the file paths for specified user only

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in array as below.

```
<input type="file" name="file[]">
<input type="file" name="file[]">
```

Make sure to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag.

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file[]">
<input type="file" name="file[]">
</form>
```

And if you want to select multiple files with single file input then add `multiple="multiple"`

```
<input name="file[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```